# having some problems with my hamburger icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

so someone very kindly helped me sort a few bits out on my website earlier, one of them being the hamburger menu, but im having some troubles with it.

i want it to only show when its on mobile (768px) or less, i also want it to list the nav links underneath, at the moment its showing them on the right side of the burger bar and not in a container, would anyone be able to guide me where its gone wrong?

i was expecting the nav links to show in a container beneath the burger logo preferably taking up the full width of a 768px screen and either half the screen of a medium screen or make the nav links/writing go smaller to not make them so crowded.

```js
   const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
    const navMenu = document.querySelector('.navigation ul');

    hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navMenu.classList.toggle('active')
    });
```

```css
.hamburger {
    display: block;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation {
    display: flex;
}

.navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation li {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
    .navigation {
    width: 100%;
   }

   .navigation ul {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%; 
   }

   .navigation ul.active {
    display: flex;
   }

   .navigation li {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="hamburger">☰</button>

    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropBtn">Stomping Ground<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="Intro.html">Intro</a>
                    <a href="Meet.html">Meet the team</a>
                    <a href="Roadmap.html">Roadmap</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropBtn">Training<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="How.html">How to play</a>
                    <a href="Tokenomics.html">Tokenomics</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="M.html">Multiplayer</a></li>
            <li><a href="S.html">Single player</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a></li>
            <li><button class="btnLogin-popup">Login</button></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I misunderstood, but the code seems to be working the way you want. As you can see, the links already display under the hamburger icon in a container (I changed the colour so you can see that). I hid the hamburger icon by only displaying it when the screen is at a max-width of 768px and I removed the margin at the sides by adding `margin:0` to the body.

Is there something else that you wanted to do?

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.navigation ul');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navMenu.classList.toggle('active')
});
```

```css
body {
margin:0 
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
}

.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation li {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block
  }
  .navigation {
    width: 100%;
    background: pink;
  }
  .navigation ul {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navigation ul.active {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navigation li {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="hamburger">☰</button>

<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropBtn">Stomping Ground<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="Intro.html">Intro</a>
        <a href="Meet.html">Meet the team</a>
        <a href="Roadmap.html">Roadmap</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropBtn">Training<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="How.html">How to play</a>
        <a href="Tokenomics.html">Tokenomics</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="M.html">Multiplayer</a></li>
    <li><a href="S.html">Single player</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a></li>
    <li><button class="btnLogin-popup">Login</button></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: wow, im not the brightest, didn't realise it was a minor colour issue, is there any way to get the burger to stay fixed to top right of screen, also the dropdown still opening to the right for me, could it be that some other css code is interfering with it? and is there anyway for the social media images to show in it sitting horizontally to each other?

Comment: If you have other CSS code that might be interfering with it. Can you put all of your code into a jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ or codepen https://codepen.io? I'll try to take another look at it.